# r programming - how to split each element of a vector into subset based on a unique character

Tags: r

I have a vector with numerous elements. Each element is a string of characters. For example, consider the following vector:

```
[1] "1 \t1.02  \t2.2 \t1.2 \t1.01 \t1.08 \t785 \t"                
[2] "2 \t1.03  \t5 \t2.6 \t1.5 \t1.01 \t948 \t"             
[3] "3 \t1.03  \t11 \t2.9 \t1.6 \t1.01 \t942 \t"              
[4] "4 \t1.04  \t7 \t3.7 \t1.6 \t1.01 \t848 \t"
```

I want to convert this vector into a data frame. Each element represents a row. Notice in each element of the vector, the is the combination of the text \t; this represents the end of a column. In the example above, the vector would become the data frame shown below:

```
    C1   C2   C3   C4    C5     C6     C7
1   1   1.02  2.2  1.2   1.01   1.08   785                
2   2   1.03  5    2.6   1.5    1.01   948             
3   3   1.03  11   2.9   1.6    1.01   942              
4   4   1.04  7    3.7   1.6    1.01   848
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't been able to find an example that will allow me to get started.

Comment: What's the data source? Those are just tabs....

Comment: `do.call(rbind,strsplit(c('1 3 5','4 5 6'),' '))` is one way to get a matrix, which you can coerce to a data.frame.

Comment: `read.table(text = x)` should be fine, where `x` is the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on the comment by @RichardScriven, you can obtain a dataframe in your case like this:

```
df <- read.table(text=sapply(1:length(v), function(x) c(v[x],"\n")))
names(df) <- paste0("C",1:ncol(df))
#> df
#  C1   C2   C3  C4   C5   C6  C7
#1  1 1.02  2.2 1.2 1.01 1.08 785
#2  2 1.03  5.0 2.6 1.50 1.01 948
#3  3 1.03 11.0 2.9 1.60 1.01 942
#4  4 1.04  7.0 3.7 1.60 1.01 848
```

The inner part of the first line, with `sapply`, joins the vectors to create a single character string, however with additional "\n"s denoting the end of each line (row). The function `read.table()` with the option `text=` converts the resulting character string into a data.frame.

The second line is used to assign the names of the columns as requested.

**data**

```
v <- vector()
v[1] <- "1 \t1.02  \t2.2 \t1.2 \t1.01 \t1.08 \t785 \t"
v[2] <- "2 \t1.03  \t5 \t2.6 \t1.5 \t1.01 \t948 \t"
v[3] <- "3 \t1.03  \t11 \t2.9 \t1.6 \t1.01 \t942 \t"
v[4] <- "4 \t1.04  \t7 \t3.7 \t1.6 \t1.01 \t848 \t"
```

Comment: Or instead of `sapply`, you can `paste`, i.e. `read.table(text=paste(gsub(' +|\t$', '', v), collapse='\n'), sep='\t', col.names=paste0('C', 1:7))`

Comment: That's better, indeed.